# Why "macOS folder archive" doesn't get signed with install4j

Tags: macos, code-signing, install4j

I can't figure out why **archive/macOS folder archive** doesn't get signed by install4j  even when it's instructed to "Sign macOS media files" in general settings. Looking into the logs during the build I do see that DMG gets signed.
The signing certificate is good because I've got another app signed without problems, the only difference is that media is **installer/macOS folder**. So it signs the DMG and doesn't sign the app folder inside? What's the point? I must be missing something.

I am trying to achieve a very simple flow for the user - click on dmg, drag the app archive to the Applications and click to run. No installers needed. It works great until the dmg gets downloaded from the internet, Mac decides that it's dangerous because there is no developer signature and fun begins... How do I make this signature with install4j?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
(install4j version is 6.1.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to achieve a very simple flow for the user - click on dmg, drag the >app archive to the Applications and click to run.

Then use the macOS single bundle archive and not the macOS folder installer.

> So it signs the DMG and doesn't sign the app folder inside?

No, both the DMG and all generated launchers are signed by install4j for the macOS folder installer.

Note: For macOS 10.14, you will need install4j 7.0.6+ otherwise the signature is reported as invalid.

---

Update after discussion in the comments:

In your case, the executable is a shell script. For mach-o binaries, the `codesign` tool on macOS saves the signature directly inside the binary, for non-mach-o binaries, it saves extended HFS+ attributes of the file Info.plist. These extended attributes would not be picked up by install4j even if you build on macOS, they will be lost at runtime and the signature will be invalid.

I'm afraid that the only way forward is to use a generated launcher.

Comment: I have to use my own launcher, this is why I can't use the bundle because it forces me to use the instal4j launcher which I can't create (another story, not for this issue). So, I found a way around by making the app folder and placing everything in it so that Mac will run it - and it does. All left is to sign that folder in dmg to keep Mac happy. I am on Mac 10.13.4, will I need intall4j7 to make this work?

Comment: `All left is to sign that folder in dmg` -> You can either sign a DMG or an application bundle, a plain folder cannot be signed. If you have your own launcher, then just sign it yourself and add it to the distribution tree.

Comment: As far as I understand the application bundle is a plain folder, no? What sits in the DMG is that particular bundle (app folder of defined structure so that Mac can execute the contents of it). I created it myself following the Apple rules for app bundle. It works fine when I do local installation which proves that bundle is structured OK, including the launcher and the JRE which sits right in there. The bad part is that when I download this same DMG from my distribution site, Mac refuses to run it because it's not signed. So, I am confused - what needs to be signed? And how?

Comment: The signature of an application bundle is written to certain files, there is no general concept for signing directories. To sign an application bundle yourself, see https://successfulsoftware.net/2012/08/30/how-to-sign-your-mac-os-x-app-for-gatekeeper/

Comment: Yes, I could probably do this myself by pulling apart the DMG file, signing the app bundle and executable inside it, putting it back into DMG. My question was why install4j doesn't do this for me? I can't use "macOS single bundle archive" because it demands launchers which demand main class in turn. I don't have that. My app is bootstrapped by shell script and powered up Java Service Wrapper which boots the JVM. I will try to sign the executable individually, may be it will pass...

Comment: Nope, signing individual files didn't help.. there must be something more complicated than that.

Comment: I understand your use case, but install4j does not sign other application bundles in your distribution tree. You should not pull apart the DMG, but rather sign your application bundle beforehand with the "codesign" executable as explained in the link three comments above.  If you just have a shell script, you cannot sign that on macOS, you need an application bundle.

Comment: `sign your application bundle beforehand`, Ingo, thank you for the patience, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve with install4j. [Here is the application bundle](https://postimg.cc/image/bgpu1z517/). Everything is in there including the launching shell script to run the native MacOS executable to bootstrap the JVM. Do you mean that it isn't possible to sign this during install4j build?